# Mathematica – Optimize over array variable

Tags: arrays, optimization, syntax, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have a function of some x and an array variable.

```js
A = Array[a, 2];
f[x_] := (x-.5)^2 + a[1]^2 + a[2]^2
```

Now I would like to minimize over both, which leads to an error.

```
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, A}]
```

*FindMinimum::nrlnum: The function value {0.707107,1.41421 a[1.]} is not
    a list of real numbers with dimensions {2} at {x,A} = {1.,1.}. >>*

**How would I have to write this?**

In contrast, it works fine for non-array variables.

```
f[x_] := (x-.5)^2 + y^2 + z^2;
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, y, z}]
{0., {x -> 0.5, y -> 0., z -> 0.}}
```

And, curiously, it works fine if I have only the array variable.

```
A = Array[a, 3]
f := (a[3] - .5)^2 + a[1]^2 + a[2]^2
FindMinimum[f, A]
{0., {a[1] -> 0., a[2] -> 0., a[3] -> 0.5}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do :

```
bigA = Array[a, 2];
f[x_] := (x - .5)^2 + Total[bigA^2]

FindMinimum[f[x], Flatten[{x, bigA}]]
(* {0., {x -> 0.5, a[1] -> 0., a[2] -> 0.}} *)
```

Comment: This is it, thanks. Actually, the last part seems to be sufficient – I don't even have to rewrite the function definition like you did (which would be impractical in the general case, because the function might be assembled automatically somewhere else). You might want to edit this to make your answer even more concise.